# How to show evaluation map $\mathbb{Z}[x,y] \rightarrow R$ given by $\text{ev}_{(r,s)}(xy)=rs$ is a ring homomorphism? $R$ is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show evaluation map $\mathbb{Z}[x,y] \rightarrow R$, $R$ is commutative, given by $\text{ev}_{(r,s)}(xy)=rs$ is a ring homomorphism? Where $r,s \in R$

I am confused on how to show this I would try to do this, but it doesn't seem right to me. I have seen an answer that is too complicated for the tools I have at hand.

Attempt: $$\text{ev}_{(r,s)}((f+g)(x,y))=\text{ev}_{(r,s)}(f(x,y)+g(x,y))=f(r,s)+g(r,s)=\text{ev}_{(r,s)}(f(x,y))+\text{ev}_{(r,s)}(g(x,y))$$

and $$\text{ev}_{(r,s)}((fg)(x,y))=\text{ev}_{(r,s)}(f(xy)g(xy))=f(rs)g(rs)=\text{ev}_{(r,s)}f(x,y)\text{ev}_{(r,s)}g(x,y)$$

Comment: You may also want to argue that $1$ maps to $1$, i.e. the map is unital. Otherwise, it looks like you have the ideas.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow but since $R$ does not necessarily contain $\mathbb{Z}$ or a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Tasso, Is there anything missing ? May be $R$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra

Comment: @Why I haven't learned about $\mathbb{Z}$ algebras, how about I write $f(r,s)$ as $\tilde{f}(r,s)$ where each coefficient $a_k$ of $x^iy^j|_{(r,s)}$ is given by $\iota(a_k)$?

Comment: @Tasso, ohh I see. When I said $R$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$ algebra, it just means there is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $R$. It is the definition

Comment: @Why how does $R$ being a $\mathbb{Z}$ algebra play into this? This could really help me.

Comment: @Tasso, because of your first comment above

Comment: @Why but how can I use that in my proof attempt?

Comment: @Why since $R$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$ algebra can i write the evaluation map as $f(x,y) \mapsto f(r,s)$?

Comment: @Tasso, I think you don't need information about $R$. The evaluation map $p(x,y) \mapsto p(r,s)$ is a ring homomorphism

Comment: I'm pretty sure $R$ should be a $\mathbb Z$-algebra, since the constant polynomials have to go somewhere.

Comment: @Rushy don't the constants $a_0$ go to $a_0 \cdot 1 \in R$?

Comment: How does $R$ being a $\mathbb{Z}$ algebra help me?

Comment: @Tasso, you have shown that $ev_{(r,s)}$ is additive. To show $ev_{(r,s)}$ is multiplicative, you just need to consider two monomials, say $a_{ij}x^iy^j$ and $b_{lm}x^ly^m$ of $f$ and $g$ respectively. This is easy because $ev_{(r,s)}((a_{ij}x^iy^j)(b_{lm}x^ly^m))=ev_{(r,s)}(a_{ij}b_{lm}x^iy^jx^ly^m)=a_{ij}b_{lm}r^is^jr^ls^m=(a_{ij}r^is^j)(b_{lm}r^ly^m)=ev_{(r,s)}(a_{ij}x^iy^j) \cdot ev_{(r,s)}(b_{lm}x^ly^m)$.

Comment: @Tasso, Just a short comment, here $R$ is indeed a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra because you are mapping $a_0 \mapsto a_0 \cdot 1$, which is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f \in \mathbb Z[x, y]$, then you can write $f = \sum_{i = 0}^n \sum_{j = 0}^m a_{ij}x^iy^j$. We can view $f$ as a polynomial in $R[x, y]$ by sending $f$ to the polynomial $\tilde{f} = \sum_{i = 0}^n \sum_{j = 0}^m (a_{ij} \cdot 1)x^iy^j$. Note this is what you suggested doing in one of your earlier comments.

Then you can write $\mathrm{ev}_{(r, s)} : \mathbb Z[x, y] \to R$ as the composition $\mathrm{ev}_{(r, s)} = \widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)} \circ \varphi$, where $\varphi : \mathbb Z[x, y] \to R[x, y]$ is the map such that $\varphi(f) = \tilde{f}$ and $\widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)} : R[x, y] \to R$ is the map sending a polynomial $g \in R[x, y]$ to $\widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)}(g) = g(r, s)$.

Since the map $\mathbb Z \to R$ sending $a \to a \cdot 1$ is a ring homomorphism, you can verify that $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism (since everything happens coefficientwise).

To verify that $\widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)}$ is a ring homomorphism, note that for the constant polynomial $1 \in R[x, y]$ you have $$\widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)}(1) = 1,$$
and for $g, g' \in R[x, y]$ you have $$\widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)}(g + g') = (g + g')(r, s) = g(r, s) + g'(r, s) = \widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)}(g) + \widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)}(g').$$

I'll leave verifying that $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism and that $\widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)}(g g') = \widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)}(g)\widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)}(g')$ to you.

Once you have shown this, you can conclude that since $\mathrm{ev}_{(r, s)}$ is the composition of the ring homomorphisms $\widetilde{\mathrm{ev}}_{(r, s)}$ and $\varphi$, it is a ring homomorphism.